# Office 365 - Create a User Group and add this to TermStore Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, office-365-developer

I want to know how to create a users group in Office 365 Admin using PowerShell.
Is there a possibility to add this group to TermStore Administrators and TermSet Contributor - Through Powershell only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider the following options for creating a Group:

### Using [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35588)

[New-SPOSiteGroup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161384(v=office.15).aspx) cmdlet creates a new group in a SharePoint Online site collection, for example:

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@contoso.com
New-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA -Group "Project Leads" -PermissionLevels "Full Control"
```

### Consume CSOM/REST APIs in PowerShell

How to create SharePoint Group using CSOM in PowerShell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")

Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}


Function Create-SPOGroup([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context,[string]$Title,[string]$Description) 
{ 
    $info=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.GroupCreationInformation 
    $info.Title=$Title
    $info.Description=$Description
    $group=$Context.Web.SiteGroups.Add($info) 
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()      
}
```

Usage

```
$UserName = "username@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Create-SPOGroup -Context $context -Title "Foo" -Description ""
$context.Dispose()
```

---

Regarding adding *TermStore Administrators*, AFAIK it is **only** supported via Server Side Object Model using [TermStore.AddTermStoreAdministrator method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.termstore.addtermstoreadministrator.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can we add Group Manager , Contributor , owner to a Group and TermSet in TermStore in SharePoint Online using Powershell? Something like what is explained here - http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/entryid/435/Creating-Managed-Metadata-Terms-in-SharePoint-with-PowerShell