# How to create several groups in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

Do you know if there's a way to create several groups in sharepoint online by using powershell for instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$grpname = "Music","Movies","Famous_Singers","HollyWood"  

Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential admin@contoso.com

foreach ($group in $grpname) { 
    New-SPOSiteGroup -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA -Group $group -PermissionLevels "Full Control"
}
```

The above code is not tested, but logic should be correct

[Reference here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138437/office-365-create-a-user-group-and-add-this-to-termstore-users)

Comment: Thank you. The idea is to create several groups at the same time. Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: Add some group names in array and then use for each loop

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you. Is there way to execute it without the permission level? and how can I specify the group owner of each group?

Comment: checkout this https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Manage-Office-365-Groups-with-PowerShell-aeb669aa-1770-4537-9de2-a82ac11b0540?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Comment: this is not to create sharepoint groups